# Install php 5.6 on centos 7

Tags: php, installation, centos

I am trying to install php 5.6 on my centos 7.
I tried this but each time, php 7.1 is installed using this process (see link below)
https://serverok.in/how-to-install-php-5-6-on-oracle-linux-7

Any help or idea will be nice.

Many thanks in advance :)

Comment: **Danger** PHP 5.6 is beyond end of life. It hasn't had a security update for 3 years and 2 months. You should not use it. For that matter, 7.1 hasn't had a security update in 2 years, 3 months either. Upgrade to something supported.

Comment: As stated by @Quentin, you **should** consider using the currently supported version of PHP. However, if you have to (due to some **very very special** reasons) , then (1) uninstall the current PHP (7.1), then (2) download the old version , and (3) manually install it. But you have to be responsible for any security problems in the old PHP version. (you have been warned)